# How to open in new tab with my current code using if statement

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using wordpress, this is the code from a plugin, I created two tabs. 1: streams, 2: downloads. if they click a link with embed code it will load a video onto a page, but if they click an external url they get 404 error because it's loading onto my page not opening in new tab. I want to keep the embed to load in my page, and external url to open in new tab. Using if statement but i dont know how. This is my [page](http://betamode.pe.hu/watch/electricity/), i want to copy [this](http://www.cinezen.me/watch-the-proposal-2009-online-free/) (we are using the same plugin) click at the stream in the bottom it will load the video with embed, and click the download links, it will open in new tab.

```
// the original code from plugin

<div class="float-left">
    <a href="<?=get_option('url') ?>/wpwm-redirect?link_id=<?=$t_link->linkID ?>"<?php if($t_link->link_type == 'Embed') echo ' class="thickbox"'; ?>><?=$t_link->link_title ?></a>
</div>


// here's my edited code
<div class="float-left">
    <a id="default-video" onclick="ayeLoadVideo('/wpwm-redirect?link_id=<?=$t_link->linkID ?>'); return false;" href="/wpwm-redirect?link_id=<?=$t_link->linkID ?>"> <?=$t_link->link_title ?> </a> 
</div>

<script>
            var default_video = document.getElementById('default-video').getAttribute('href');
            ayeLoadVideo(default_video);
            function ayeLoadVideo(link){
                document.getElementById("video-container").innerHTML = '<h1><center><font color="#FFF">Loading...</font></center></h1>';
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("video-container").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", link, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }


</script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for window.open? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: I am looking to open a link in new tab if the link_type is eternal. not embed